# How can I detect element visibility using zombie js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

On `browser.visit(url, function(){})` how can I detect element visibility within the callback using zombie js? Is this possible with headless browsers?

Answer (score 3):

In zombie 2.0 -

```
browser.assert.style('#show-hide.hidden', 'display', 'none');
browser.assert.style('#show-hide:not(.hidden)', 'display', '');
```

Comment: thanks - its been a minute since i've toyed w zombie, but i'll give this a shot